# Problems deploying Extensions in DotNetNuke on Azure Website

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke

I have just created a website for my company and chosen to install the DotNetNuke Framework into the site.

My problem comes when I try to deploy Extentions.  I have just bought the "Advanced Business Directory" and "Live Blog" extensions and neither will install correctly.

When I try to deploy the "Live Blog" Extensions I get the following error:

```
"A critical error has occurred. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\coworking-foundation\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\Install\Module\'."
```

When I try to deploy the "Advanced Business Directory" I get the following top level error:

```
Error loading files from temporary folder - see below
```

With the details being:

```
StartJob    Starting Installation
Info    Starting Installation - AdvancedBusinessDirectory
Info    Starting Installation - Script
Info    Begin Sql execution
Info    Creating backup of previous version - Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\00.00.01.SqlDataProvider
Info    Created - Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\00.00.01.SqlDataProvider
Info    Executing 00.00.01.SqlDataProvider
Info    Start Sql execution: 00.00.01.SqlDataProvider file
Failure SQL Execution resulted in following Exceptions: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'NOT FOR REPLICATION' is not supported in this version of SQL Server. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteADOScript(String SQL) at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteScript(String Script, Boolean UseTransactions) /************************************************************/ /***** SqlDataProvider *****/ /***** *****/ /***** *****/ /***** Note: To manually execute this script you must *****/ /***** perform a search and replace operation *****/ /***** for dbo. and *****/ /***** *****/ /************************************************************/ /*==============================================================*/ /* Table: dbo.ZLDNN_Business */ /*==============================================================*/ if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'dbo.[ZLDNN_Business]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsTable') = 1) BEGIN create table dbo.ZLDNN_Business ( BusinessID int not null IDENTITY(1, 1), ModuleID int null, Name nvarchar(200) null, Address nvarchar(200) null, Description nvarchar(4000) null, Website nvarchar(200) null, Email nvarchar(100) null, Phone nvarchar(100) null, Fax nvarchar(100) null, Postal nvarchar(50) null, Logo nvarchar(200) null, Unit nvarchar(100) null, Street nvarchar(200) null, City nvarchar(100) null, Region nvarchar(100) null, Country nvarchar(100) null, Lat nvarchar(100) null, Lng nvarchar(100) null, IsApproved bit null, IsFeatured bit null, OwnerUserID int null, CreatedDate datetime null, UpdatedDate datetime null, ExpiredDate datetime null, ViewCount int null, Keywords nvarchar(200) null, ) ALTER TABLE dbo.[ZLDNN_Business] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ZLDNN_Business] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BusinessID]) CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ZLDNN_Business] ON dbo.[ZLDNN_Business] ([ModuleID]) ALTER TABLE dbo.[ZLDNN_Business] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ZLDNN_Business_Modules] FOREIGN KEY ([ModuleID]) REFERENCES dbo.[Modules] ([ModuleID]) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT FOR REPLICATION END System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'NOT FOR REPLICATION' is not supported in this version of SQL Server. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteADOScript(String SQL) at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteScript(String Script, Boolean UseTransactions) /*==============================================================*/ /* Table: dbo.ZLDNN_BusinessCategory */ /*==============================================================*/ if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessCategory]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsTable') = 1) BEGIN create table dbo.ZLDNN_BusinessCategory ( CategoryID int not null IDENTITY(1, 1), ModuleID int null, Title nvarchar(200) null, Description nvarchar(1000) null, ImagePath nvarchar(500) null, ParentID int null, Level int null, ViewOrder int null, ) ALTER TABLE dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessCategory] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ZLDNN_BusinessCategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CategoryID]) CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ZLDNN_BusinessCategory] ON dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessCategory] ([ModuleID]) ALTER TABLE dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessCategory] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ZLDNN_BusinessCategory_Modules] FOREIGN KEY ([ModuleID]) REFERENCES dbo.[Modules] ([ModuleID]) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT FOR REPLICATION END System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'NOT FOR REPLICATION' is not supported in this version of SQL Server. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteADOScript(String SQL) at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteScript(String Script, Boolean UseTransactions) /*==============================================================*/ /* Table: dbo.ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory */ /*==============================================================*/ if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsTable') = 1) BEGIN create table dbo.ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory ( BusinessAssignedCategoryID int not null IDENTITY(1, 1), CategoryID int not null, BusinessID int not null, ) ALTER TABLE dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BusinessAssignedCategoryID]) CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory] ON dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory] ([BusinessAssignedCategoryID]) ALTER TABLE dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory_ZLDNN_BusinessCategory] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) REFERENCES dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessCategory] ([CategoryID]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ALTER TABLE dbo.[ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ZLDNN_BusinessAssignedCategory_ZLDNN_Business] FOREIGN KEY ([BusinessID]) REFERENCES dbo.[ZLDNN_Business] ([BusinessID]) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT FOR REPLICATION END System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'NOT FOR REPLICATION' is not supported in this version of SQL Server. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteADOScript(String SQL) at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteScript(String Script, Boolean UseTransactions)
```

There is more in the SQL error, but it's much the same for about 10 different modules in the same package.

Does anyone have these extensions working, or any idea about how I can proceed with installing them?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Live Blog is Azure compatible. Make sure you're installing the latest version. http://www.mandeeps.com/downloads.aspx